# What is the name for this turn-based property trading game?

Tags: microeconomics, game-theory, property

Does anyone know what the following allocation strategy is called?

Problem:

- How to allocate N rooms to N roommates? Example: allocate 4 rooms
  (1,2,3,4) amongst 4 roommates (A,B,C,D) total rent of $4000.

Allocation Game:

1. Each roommate assigned a starting random room; all rooms are priced
       at an equal \$1000.
2. Roommate A's turn: has the option to swap rooms with someone.  In
   the swap: the traded-for room increases its price to \$1050, the
   traded-away room decreases its price to \$950.
3. Roommate B's turn: has the option to swap rooms with someone. Every
   time a room is traded away its price decreases \$50, similarly the
   traded-for room increases by \$50.
4. Turns continue indefinitely until 4 turns pass with no roommate
   wanting to swap.

Result:

- Each room is priced at an equilibrium where no further trading is desired.

Does this form of iterative trading game have a name?

Comment: Market game with \$50 price increments?